# Spring framework error : NonUniqueResultException: result returns more than one elements

Tags: spring, aop

I am using spring framework to create a web application. One of my task now is once a controller methods is triggered an email has to be sent to the user at the same time which an Async task is running background. I am using Aspect oriented programming framework. Now I am facing an issue where the email feature is not being triggered. I am getting the following error message below.

```
 .a.i.SimpleAsyncUncaughtExceptionHandler : Unexpected error occurred invoking async method 

javax.persistence.NonUniqueResultException: result returns more than one elements
```

Below is my Async method:

```
@Async
@AfterReturning(pointcut="execution(* com.kontron.web.hr.controllers.a.download(..))"
        + "&& args(email, redirAttrs) ")
public void totalDownload(String email, RedirectAttributes redirAttrs) throws Exception {

}
```

This is the code which is throwing me the error exception:

```
DownloadInfo dload = dlRepo.getDownloadUsersByYear(user.getUserName(), year);
```

I tried to apply the following methods.

```
List<DownloadInfo> dload= dlRepo.getDownloadUsersByYear2(user.getUserName(), year);
```

But still its failing. Can someone help me out on this.

Thanks

Comment: The problem has nothing to do with asynch, aop or emails, it's your usage of spring data.  Your repo method is typed to return a single instance of `DownloadInfo` but more than one is matching your query.  If you change the return type of the repo to a `List<DownloadInfo>` what happens?

Comment: The model method is not recognized. For example getDownloadTime() method is showing undefined.